# DNN 7 upgrade install page is blank

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am getting a blank page when I try to install upgrade of DNN 7 anyone can  help?

http://arcel.brainyyack.net/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade

Comment: I'm not sure you want to post the link to the page that is supposed to kick off your upgrade.  1000 people clicking on that won't result in anything good happening.

Answer (score 1):

Edited PER THESE COMMENTS....

OP: when upgrading dnn be sure that your web server meets the requirements, dnn7 requires iis7 or greater to run. Also make sure the .net framework is set to 4.0 in the app pool.

A blank page upgrade can be caused by a number of things, server requirements being one.

You should likely start the dnn upgrade process over by restoring your backup, then following the upgrade steps.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions here. It encourages more off-topic questions, even if the question is closed. ("I'll post anyway; maybe I'll get an answer before it gets closed."). In addition, this is not an answer. It's at best a comment to the original question.

Comment: The question isn't necessarily off topic, but is poorly worded, I'll give the guy the benefit of the doubt and try to be helpful